# How to load HTML and Script dynamically as user Requires it

Tags: html, asp.net

I am creating a single page application and I am new to it. The problem is that application has lots and lots of HTML which I dont want to be loaded at client side. I want HTML to be loaded when it is required. For example there is a module inside some pop up. i want this module's HTML to be loaded when user click to open that module. What should I do for that? Any framework or any article which can help me in that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **How to load HTML and Script dynamically as user Requires it** study basic ASP.NET *IF ELSE* conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AJAX` for this 
AJAX enable the client to send the request from client to server when the javascript is called.
You can see the [working example for loading different modules here](http://ezone.host-ed.me/module.html)

In this exapmle I made a GET request for module1.txt, module2.txt and module3.txt. You can use your asp page instead and also use POST request in AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` for registering a script at run-time.

What you need is something like below in event code/ where you need in c#:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), this.ClientID, "JavaScriptmethod()", true);
```

Replace your js method name with JavaScriptmethod and it will be called at run-time